# get error while updating object in trigger test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, failing-tests

I have a trigger on custom object object called File_Uploaded__c which has an attribute : `IsMain__c` of type `checkbox`, and the trigger maintains only one file as main :

```
trigger setIsMain on File_Uploaded__c (before update) {

// this trigger will only be executed if we change IsMain__c field from false to true
list<File_Uploaded__c> filesToChange = new list<File_Uploaded__c>();
for(File_Uploaded__c f: Trigger.new) {
    if(f.IsMain__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(f.Id).IsMain__c && f.IsMain__c == true) {    
       filesToChange.add(f);
    }
}

if(filesToChange.size() > 0) {
    File_Uploaded__c fileToUpdate = filesToChange.get(0);
    List<File_Uploaded__c> oldMainFile = [select Id, IsMain__c from File_Uploaded__c where IsMain__c = true and Case__c = :fileToUpdate.Case__c and Id != :fileToUpdate.Id];
    if (oldMainfile.size() > 0) {
        oldMainfile.get(0).IsMain__c = false;
        update oldMainfile.get(0);
    }        

    // get the corresponding case and appliance of the new main file 
    Case caseFile = [select  EligibleSupport__c, Product__c, Software_version__c, CustomerProject__c from Case where Id = :fileToUpdate.Case__c];  
    caseFile.Product__c = fileToUpdate.Product__c;
    caseFile.Software_version__c = fileToUpdate.Version__c;

    if (fileToUpdate.Asset2__c != null ) {
         Asset2__c asset = [select Support_Contract_Level__c, Support_Contract_End_Date__c, Opportunity__r.Project__c from Asset2__c where Id = :fileToUpdate.Asset2__c]; 
         caseFile.EligibleSupport__c = asset.Support_Contract_End_Date__c < system.now() ? 'Expired' : asset.Support_Contract_Level__c;
         caseFile.CustomerProject__c = asset.Opportunity__r.Project__c;   
    }else {
        caseFile.EligibleSupport__c = '';
         caseFile.CustomerProject__c = null; 
    }       

    // update the corresponding case of the new main file                        
    update caseFile;
}
```

and when i write a `test class`:

```
@isTest
public class TestFileIsMain {
static testmethod void testIsMain() {

    File_Uploaded__c f = new File_Uploaded__c();
    f.FileName__c = 'testTrigger';
    f.Case__c = '500f0000005BBQPAA4';
    f.IsMain__c = false;
    insert f;

    f.IsMain__c = true;
    update f;

    List<File_Uploaded__c> allMainFiles = [select Id from File_Uploaded__c where Case__c =:f.Case__c and IsMain__c = true];

    System.assertEquals(1, allMainFiles.size());
}
```

}

i got several errors :

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   a2tf0000000Dx8OAAS; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   setIsMain: execution of BeforeUpdate
>   caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to
>   SObject Trigger.setIsMain: line 20, column 1: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what your trigger does is set one main as File per case so here's an example for the test class:

```
@isTest
   public class TestFileIsMain {
       static testMethod void testIsMain() {
           Case c = new Case(Name = 'Test Name', your_fields_here = '...');
           insert c;

           File_Uploaded__c f1 = new File_Uploaded__c(Name = 'test1', IsMain = true, Case__c = c.Id);
           insert f1;

           File_Uploaded__c f2 = new File_Uploaded__c(Name = 'test2', IsMain = false, Case__c = c.Id);
           insert f2;  
           File_Uploaded__c f3 = new File_Uploaded__c(Name = 'test3', IsMain = false,  Case__c = c.Id);        
           insert f3; 

           f2.IsMain__c = true;                                      

           test.startTest();       
           update f2;
           test.stopTest();

           List<File_Uploaded__c> allMainFiles = [select Id from File_Uploaded__c where IsMain__c = true and Case__c = :c.Id];

           System.assertEquals(1, allMainFiles.size());
       }
   }
```

you should first create a `Case` (the `Id` is generated automatically) and insert it and then assign it to `Case__c` field, and the test part should be between `test.startTest()`  and `test.stopTest()` because the trigger is fired before update,  so then you can then query what you want from your object.

Comment: you are welcome, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your TestClass has no access to the records on your data. You need to create a Case in the testclass and use the ID of that. Something like:

```
Case c = new Case(Name = 'Test Name', your_required_fields = 'test'); // Fill in whatever fields are required
insert c;
// init your filetoupload
f.Case__c = c.Id;
```

You don't give `Case c` an id, as the system does this on insert.

Comment: you mean like this: `Case c = new Case(Name = 'Test Name', Id = 'myId''); ` and then i asign it to Case__c ??

But the probem is that Case__c it's just the id of the Case and then i need to check if there's effectively 1 main file or 2 because that's what the trigger does

Comment: No, not like this. I will make an edit, maybe you will see it then.